# BatchUpdate JDBCTemplate - пакетное выполнение sql-запросов Java

Tags: java, spring, java-hashmap

Есть метод, который обновляет данные в БД по HashMap

```
public void setHashMapFieldsDB(HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap){

    String SQL = "UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = ? WHERE language_id = 3 AND product_id = ?";

    for (Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());

    }

}
```

Подскажите, как его переделать, чтоб sql-запросы выполнялись в пакете? С помощью BatchUpdate или другим способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант

```
public void setHashMapFieldsDB(HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap){

    String SQL = "UPDATE oc_product_description SET name = ? WHERE language_id = 3 AND product_id = ?";

    List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> data = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.entrySet());
    jdbcTemplateObject.batchUpdate(SQL, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, data.get(i).getValue());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, data.get(i).getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return data.size();
        }
    });
}
```